# Rsync a list of files into a single directory

Tags: rsync

I have a list of files that are in various directories on a remote machine that I want to rsync to a single directory on my local machine.

For an individual file `user@remote:dir1/dir2/file1 ~/local` does what I want; i.e. `~/local/file1`

If I use `--files-from` then it creates the directory structure giving me `~local/dir1/dir2/file1` which I don't want.

n.b. I am aware that duplicate file names from different directories would cause files to be overwritten in `~/local`

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `rsync` (`man rsync`) offers this particular scenario as one of its suggestions,

> `--files-from=FILE` Using this option allows you to specify the exact list of files to transfer (as read from the specified FILE or '`-`' for standard  input).   It also tweaks the default behavior of rsync to make transferring just the specified files and directories easier:
>
> o The `--relative` (`-R`) option is implied, which preserves the path information that is specified for each item in the file (use `--no-relative` or `--no-R` if you want to turn that off).
>
> [...]

Applying this to your question,

```
rsync -av --files-from=/tmp/filelist --no-R user@remote:dir1/dir2/file1 ~/local
```

I would opine that having two or more files with the same name would have undefined behaviour, possibly causing `rsync` to fail with an error due to mismatching checksums. Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware there's an issue with repeated file names and I deal with it when creating my list.